# Regular expression for string containing repetition of alphabet after single alphabet

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am looking for String which can have repetition of any alphabet preceding single alphabet (like abbb or cddd) from A to Z.

I am using `@"\b([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1,})\b"`which is partially working. Not completely.I need to combine/merge these regex.
I would appreciate if anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with the following regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z])\1+\b");
```

`([A-Za-z])` captures 2nd character from the word, `\1` references this character and `+` quantifier verifies that all characters till word boundary are equal to the captured 2nd character.

Comment: yeah its working and what if we have to create a regex for repetition of two alphabets  like aaaaabbbbbb or aabbbb or abbbbb or ab or aaaab. in all the examples there are two alphabets [a-z] and they both can be repeated 1 or many times.

Comment: Well, then you can use `Regex(@"\b([A-Za-z])\1*([A-Za-z])\2*\b")`.

Answer (score 1):

If `aaaa` or `bbb` shouldn't match, I'd go with this one:

```
\b([A-Za-z])(?!\1)([A-Za-z])\2+\b
```

Otherwise @CodeFuller's regex works fine.

Comment: Nice catch regarding `aaaa` case. Waiting for OP comment whether he expects such input to be matched.